# Sign in screen design in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, user-interface

**How to design Sign In screen in Native Android like this?**

This is already done in Flutter but I want to make this design in Native Android.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This....
Make three drawable resorces files
1-box_white

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:width="200dp" android:gravity="center">
        <shape >
            <solid android:color= "#FFFFff"/>
            <stroke android:width="2dp"/>
            <corners android:radius="30dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:width="250dp" android:gravity="center" android:top="20dp" >
        <shape >
            <solid android:color= "#f0f0f0"/>
            <stroke android:width="2dp"/>
            <corners android:radius="30dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="40dp" >
        <shape >
            <solid android:color= "#FFffFF"/>
            <stroke android:width="2dp"/>
            <corners android:radius="30dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

2-box_blue

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color= "#0000FF"/>
    <corners android:radius="300dp"/>
</shape>
```

3-gradient_blue

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#00ffff"
        android:endColor="#0000ff"
        android:angle="90"/>


</shape><shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#00ffff"
        android:endColor="#0000ff"
        android:angle="90"/>


</shape>
```

Then write this code in your LoginAvtivity.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="@drawable/gradient_blue"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/box_white"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:text="Sign In"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/idEmail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:autofillHints=""
                android:background="@null"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:hint="Email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                tools:ignore="TextFields" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/idPassword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:autofillHints=""
                android:background="@null"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                tools:ignore="TextFields" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/idForgot"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                android:text="Forgot Password"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/box_blue"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingStart="10dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                    android:text="Sign In"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"

                    />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/idSignin"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
                    android:paddingStart="10dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                    android:text="->"
                    android:background="@drawable/arrow" //please upload // a png picture here for better look.
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"

                    />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Hope this works.

*EDIT*
it should look like this
[image]

Comment: its somehow worked but i need that 2 shadow as well.

Comment: @HilalAhmad shadow added in **box_white**. if you want your back ground gradiant as well please add a drawable resoures file like **box_bule** and set gradiant.Should I write code for that also.

Comment: Let me know where you need  further corrections. I will try for you.

Comment: I have added gradient background also. If you liked my efforts please accept this answer and upvote it. I shall  be highly obliged.

Comment: You may change color of your shadows and remove boundary line in **box_white** .Note that **@drawable/arrow** is the png picture you have to upload in your drawable folder.

Comment: Great, thanks for your help with the perfect solution.

Answer (score 1):

For your background, make an XML file named `gradiant.xml` and add this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:endColor="#00000000"/>    
</shape>
```

And for your card, you can use cardview or just add a rounded background to your layout. Add this to `drawables` file as to your `rounded_bacground.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
<stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#B1BCBE" />
<corners android:radius="10dp"/>
<padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" 
/>
</shape>
```